# split a string and append to it another without comma char jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I split a string and then I wanted to append another to it but it is automatically added a comma char between the split string and the appended one, below is an example:

```
var mystring="mypath/myfile0.png"
var myotherstring=mystring.split(".png")+"1.png"
```

The result is: myotherstring=mypath/**myfile0,1.png** please pay attention to the comma character. How can I append a string after splitting another without this comma char? why is it being added that comma char?

Edson

Comment: What are you trying to do with the string? Are you trying to find a certain string and replace it with another?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your following line:

```
var myotherstring=mystring.split(".png")+"1.png"
```

for this one:

```
var myotherstring=mystring.split(".png")[0]+"1.png"
```

As you were concatenating to the whole array returned by `.split()` instead of just appending to the first element in the arrray which is what you wanted.

See [**demo**](http://tinker.io/32cb0)

Comment: I'm glad this worked for you, you seem new to SO, welcome!, and remember to accept answer (check mark).

Answer (score 1):

`.join()` it:

```
var myotherstring=mystring.split(".png").join("1.png");
```

This outputs `mypath/myfile01.png`

#### [Demo for above one](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyv5m/)

And if you want get rid of `0` then use this:

```
var myotherstring=mystring.split("0.png").join("1.png");
```

This outputs `mypath/myfile1.png`

#### [Demo for above one](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyv5m/1/)